# connect postgresql with java

Tags: java, postgresql

```
package vas;

import java.sql.*;
public class ConnTO {

    public Connection conn;
    private String db;


    public ConnTO(String db) throws Exception{

        this.db=db;
        //Trying to get the driver
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");



        }
        catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
            java.lang.System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: Postgres Server JDBC");
            java.lang.System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("No JDBC Driver found in Server");
        }

        //Trying to connectpostgresql:/
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"+db,"postgres","211271");
            //conn.setCatalog(db);
            System.out.println("Connection with: "+db+"!!");
        }
        catch (SQLException E) {

            java.lang.System.out.println("SQLException: " + E.getMessage());
            java.lang.System.out.println("SQLState: " + E.getSQLState());
            java.lang.System.out.println("VendorError: " + E.getErrorCode());

        }
    }


    //Close Conn
    public void close() throws SQLException{

        try {
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Connection close ");
        } catch (SQLException E) {


            java.lang.System.out.println("SQLException: " + E.getMessage());
            java.lang.System.out.println("SQLState: " + E.getSQLState());
            java.lang.System.out.println("VendorError: " + E.getErrorCode());
            throw E;
        }

    }



}
```

Hello i create a database with postgresql and i would like to connect it with java but when i run this there is an error such as

```
ClassNotFoundException: Postgres Server JDBCorg.postgresql.Driver
java.lang.Exception: No JDBC Driver found in Server
    at vas.ConnTO.<init>(ConnTO.java:21)
    at vas.main.login(main.java:17)
    at vas.main.main(main.java:51)
```

Also i have a main class that i call the class connto and i give the name of my base

Comment: Have you tried the search function?

Comment: ... and have you tried to understand the exception message?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 0):

Class org.postgresql.Driver can't be found in your classpath. This class should be in a jar file in your classpath.